# How to get index of value in Enum in C/C++

Tags: c, indexing, enums

I've searched but could not find any solution for this issue.
I have an enum that does not start with "0" and other values are also not in sequence which is like,

```
typedef enum{
a = 8,
b = 100,
c,
d = 1,
e = 9
}numberEnum;
```

I want to get index of an element in enum like this;

```
int myIndex = getIndex(a); // myIndex = 0
int myIndex1 = getIndex(d); // myIndex1 = 3
int myIndex2 = getIndex(b); // myIndex2 = 1

int getIndex(numberEnum e)
{
    // some code here

   return index;
}
```

I should not use Array for this situation. Using enum is a must. Is there any way to achieve this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There's no direct way to do that.  But what's the goal here?  Are you looking to use this information at compile time?

Comment: Not much can be done here. You either maintain a separate list of enumerator indices (maybe `std::map<numberEnum, int>`, assuming C++), or use x-macros (or boost preprocessor witchery) to generate this list automatically. Doing it without arrays is silly, but you can generate a `switch` with x-macro or something similar.

Comment: C or C++? They're not the same language, and the solution will be different.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure what you're asking for, but I have a gut feeling [this github gist of mine](https://gist.github.com/makulik/7963331) might lead to the right direction.

Comment: there is no generic way to get the `index` of a enum value, nor can there really be one, since multiple labels can have the same value.

Comment: It sounds like a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need the _index_ of an `enum` value at all, and how would you like to use it?

Comment: Why do you need the index? What will you do with it?

Comment: Maybe you need boost:bimap. Although I am guessing what the real problem is.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=bc6aaed210591e28

Answer (score 4):

Enumerators don't have an "index value". So that's not something you can query, nor is it something you're expected to be able to. These two enumerations are functionally equivalent:

```
enum alpha { first, second };
enum beta { second = 1, first = 0 };
```

I'm sure you could do some macro stuff to generate an array mapping from enumerator names to the order they're listed in the enumeration. But that would require wrapping the enumeration and its enumerators in macros.

Answer (score 4):

You would have to make this association manually, like this:

```
int getIndex(numberEnum e)
{
   switch(e)
   {
       case a:
           return 0;
       case b:
           return 1;
       default:
           return -1;
   }
}
```

Comment: If the requirement is that you can't store the order in an array this is one alternative.

Comment: that's not working, if you have more then one identical value like a=0 and b=0 then the error duplicate case value appears.

Comment: @Mutus if you have duplicate values in your enum, (for example a and c), you could combine them in one case statement, as follows:

int getIndex(numberEnum e)
{
   switch(e)
   {
       case a:
       case c:
           return 0;
       case b:
           return 1;
       default:
           return -1;
   }
}

Comment: @MariKotlov, oh yes you right I totally forgot that. THX

Answer (score 1):

There is no semantic meaning to "indexing an enum", it is not a data structure or array, but rather a data *type*, there is no *order*, because the size of the enum is the size of a single value - "index" has no meaning. It is line asking how to index an integer; that is all an enum is, an integer with a defined subset if valid values.

You can perhaps achieve what you want (although the reason to do so escapes me) using a const array of values and using the enum to index it:

```
static const int values[] = {8, 100, 101, 1, 9} ;
typedef enum { a, b, c, d, e } numberEnum ;

numberEnum myIndex = a ; // myIndex = 0
numberEnum myIndex1 = d; // myIndex1 = 3
numberEnum myIndex2 = b; // myIndex2 = 1

int myValue = values[myIndex] ;
int mValue1 = values[myIndex1] ;
int mValue2 = values[myIndex2] ;

int valueC = values[c] ;
```

Comment: Now that makes sense.